# How to programmatically surround a string with escaped double-quote

Tags: string

It seems that my question should be common knowledge, and I thought I knew it (at some point in the distant past), but the answer escapes me tonight.  I'd like to take a string like `"foo"` and programmatically convert it to `"\"foo\""`.  Is there a built-in function for that?

I realize I can `(concat "\"" "foo" "\"")`, but I thought there is probably an existing function that does this.

Comment: You're not adding escaped double quote, only normal double quotes. They look escaped because that's how Emacs string syntax work.

Comment: If you need any sort of protection against injection, this is not the way to do it. Could you give more context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be thinking of `prin1-to-string`:

```
(prin1-to-string "foo")
=> "\"foo\""
```

You probably need some protection though (ensure it's a string, strip text properties, etc.), because you'll get more than you bargained for if you try it with a propertized string:

```
(prin1-to-string (propertize "foo" 'bar "baz"))
=> "#(\"foo\" 0 3 (bar \"baz\"))"
```

In that case you'll also need to ensure the properties have been removed.  For example:

```
(let* ((str (propertize "foo \"bar\"" 'bar "baz")))
  (set-text-properties 0 (length str) nil str)
  (prin1-to-string str))
=> "\"foo \\\"bar\\\"\""
```